# How to list only direct dependencies in mvn dependency tree command?

Tags: maven, tree, dependencies, command, transitive-dependency

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2:tree -DoutputFile=/tmp/dependencies.txt -DoutputType=dot -DappendOutput=true
```

I'm using the above command to get a list of dependencies i.e the direct and transitive dependencies. I want an alteration in the above command which would give me a list of only the direct dependencies and ignore all the transitive dependencies. I don't want to use any other command nor do i want to change the output file format. Our parsers are dependent on the output file format. Does anyone have any solution for this?

Comment: So just to be sure, you do not want to use `grep` or any other `bash` helpers?

Comment: The usual way to go would be to use `dependency:list` instead of `dependency:tree`.

Comment: The list command generates the file in an entirely different format which is not desired as far as our parsers are concerned. I see that there is an option to exclude stuff in the tree command. However, i dont see an option as to how can i exclude transitives

Comment: Mle, if there is no direct option, then we have no other choice other than modifying the generated file either using grep or using some python functions to exclude transitives

Answer (score 2):

<s>I think the [excludeTransitive property](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html#excludeTransitive) is what you want.</s>

Oh, sorry, strike that, that property is only for `dependency:list`, not `dependency:tree`.

If you were willing to live with a format change, you'd want...

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2:list -DoutputFile=/tmp/dependencies.txt -DexcludeTransitive=true
```

Comment: What if for some reason you get a `java.net.UnknownHostException` while trying to resolve a dependency which causes an overall failure, is there a way to ignore this? At the end of the day I just need the information concerning these dependencies (namely name and version) but I don't want to parse the pom.xml raw and do any given interpolations myself.